# Outlook deleting +country code

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts

I travel across Europe, Brasil and the US. I want my contact list to keep the country code for each person as part of their phone numbers. (Some people, including me, have phone or SIM cards for more than one country.) How do I get Outlook to leave the + and country code as part of a phone number. (It seems to leave the country code but, without the +, it is not recognized as a country code.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and you can easily fix it. Just open Windows Control Panel -> Phone and Modem and fill your country and area codes there. After that, restart Outlook.